# How to verify smart-contract via function?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, zksync

how to verify smart-contract via function?

I try to use this:
https://era.zksync.io/docs/api/hardhat/hardhat-zksync-verify.html#verify-smart-contract-programmatically. My code:

```
await hre.run("verify:verify", {
  address: wallet,
  contract: digitalItemSaleAddress,
  constructorArguments: [price, wallet],
});
```

This is a part of my Contract-Factory, where I create new contract for product via function createDigitalItemSale:

```
  async function createDigitalItemSale(): Promise<string> {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    const owner = accounts[0];

    // Call function createDigitalItemSale from contract-factory DigitalItemSaleFactory, with price and creator
    const createDigitalItemSaleTx = await digitalItemSaleFactoryContract.methods
      .createDigitalItemSale(digitalItemSalePrice, creatorAddress)
      .send({ from: owner });

    // Address of DigitalItemSale
    const digitalItemSaleAddress =
      createDigitalItemSaleTx.events.DigitalItemSaleCreated.returnValues[1];

    console.log(
      `Contract DigitalItemSale created with address: ${digitalItemSaleAddress}`
    );

    await hre.run("verify:verify", {
      address: wallet,
      contract: digitalItemSaleAddress,
      constructorArguments: [price, wallet],
    });

    return digitalItemSaleAddress;
  }
```

And I get this error

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'hre'.
```

And if declare "hre" I got problems with modules

```
./node_modules/@nomicfoundation/solidity-analyzer-darwin-arm64/solidity-analyzer.darwin-arm64.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

I tried

```
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types";
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment = require("hardhat")
//and other different variatons
```

How to fix that?
Will be grateful for any help

My hardhat config

```
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-deploy";
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc";
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-toolbox";
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-verify";

module.exports = {
  zksolc: {
    version: "1.3.10",
    compilerSource: "binary",
    settings: {},
  },

  defaultNetwork: "zkTestnet",

  networks: {
    zkTestnet: {
      url: "https://testnet.era.zksync.dev", // The testnet RPC URL of zkSync Era network.
      ethNetwork: "goerli", // The Ethereum Web3 RPC URL, or the identifier of the network (e.g. `mainnet` or `goerli`)
      zksync: true,
      // Verification endpoint for Goerli
      verifyURL:
        "https://zksync2-testnet-explorer.zksync.dev/contract_verification",
    },
  },

  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.17",
  },
};
```

If I tried

```
import { run } from "hardhat";

 await run("verify:verify", {
      address: wallet,
      contract: digitalItemSaleAddress,
      constructorArguments: [price, wallet],
    });
```

I got this

```
./node_modules/@nomicfoundation/solidity-analyzer-darwin-arm64/solidity-analyzer.darwin-arm64.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

I find this
https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/3663

But didn't understand how to fix my problem with modules